# button type='submit' не дает работать другим кнопкам - PHP

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, изначально у меня был `button type='submit'`
и у меня был проект что то на подобии почты. И по этой кнопке
я высылал сообщение другому пользователю, и каждый раз по клику
на кнопу у меня обновлялась страница, тогда я в функцию з
кликом по этой кнопке дописал следующее,

```
$('#button').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
)}
```

и теперь у меня не обновляться страница, но в связи с этим
пока я не обновлю страницу то другие кнопки уже без
`type='submit'` не хотят работать, и я должен теперь
сам обновлять страницу... Может кто то лучше знает в чем проблема и как сделать так что бы все кнопки работали вне зависимости
от кнопки(submit)?

Comment: И при чем здесь РНР, я стесняюсь спросить?

Comment: @Ипатьев должен был написать Ассемблер, извиняюсь

Comment: Вы точно код написали? Двух скобок не хватает `)}` в конце. Приведеный код никак не влияет на остальные submit-ы

Comment: @Greg-- исправил, но дело не в скобках, это просто пример того что я сделал у себя в функции

Comment: Такая запись никакого отношения к другим submit или кнопкам не имеет, только к одному элементу с id button, ищите проблему не в этой записи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы создаете "другие кнопки" в процессе жизни страницы, а обработчики событий им назначаете в момент загрузки страницы - когда их еще нет. Используйте делегирование.

```
$(document).on('click', '.other-buttons', function(e) {
   ...
});
```